# Cannot create View

Tags: sql, oracle, view, ddl, ora-00907

I have the following query:

```
SELECT C.company_name,
       C.JOB_TITLE, 
       E.date_joined,
       E.date_left,
       A.first_name || ' ' || A.last_name AS NAME
  FROM COMPANY C, ALUMNUS A, EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY E
 where E.alumnus_id = A.alumnus_id
   and E.company_id = C.company_id
   and E.employee_id = C.employee_id 
 order by date_joined;
```

but when I used the above code to create a view not able to do that with the following error message

```
 Error report -
 SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
 *Cause:    
 *Action:
```

I used the following code to create the view

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW AS (
SELECT C.company_name,
       C.JOB_TITLE, 
       E.date_joined,
       E.date_left,
       A.first_name || ' ' || A.last_name AS NAME
 FROM COMPANY C, ALUMNUS A, EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY E
 where E.alumnus_id = A.alumnus_id
   and E.company_id = C.company_id
   and E.employee_id = C.employee_id 
 order by date_joined);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the brackets you have in your code

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWE AS
SELECT C.company_name, C.JOB_TITLE, E.date_joined, E.date_left, A.first_name || ' ' || A.last_name AS NAME
FROM COMPANY C, ALUMNUS A, EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY E
where E.alumnus_id=A.alumnus_id 
and E.company_id=C.company_id 
and E.employee_id =C.employee_id 
order by date_joined;
```